# Java8 FunctionalInterface

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, java-stream

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean validateEnum(Class<E> clazz, String s) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(clazz).stream().anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(s));
}
```

Following is an example invocation of the above method

```
boolean isValid = validateEnum(Animal.class, "DOG");
boolean isValid = validateEnum(Color.class, "Red");
```

Can this same functionality be implemented using a Java 8 `FunctionalInterface`. I have tried creating a `BiPredicate` but am getting compiler errors when I try this.

```
final BiPredicate<String,Class> biPre = (string1, clazz) -> EnumSet.allOf(clazz).stream().anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(s));
```

Comment: `final BiPredicate<String,Class> biPre` to `final BiPredicate<String,Class<Animal>> biPre` ?

Comment: Thats not generic. If I need to implement a validateEnum for another Enum I will need to create a new BiPredicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a one way of doing it,

```
final BiPredicate<String, ? super Enum<?>> biPre = (string1, enumType) -> EnumSet
        .allOf(enumType.getDeclaringClass()).stream().anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(string1));
```

And here's the client code,

```
boolean test = biPre.test("DOG", Animal.CAT);
```

However passing an enum constant instead of a class literal seems a bit awkward here.

If you really need to use the type token here's what you should do,

```
final BiPredicate<String, Class<? extends Enum<?>>> biPre = (string1, clazz) -> Arrays
    .stream(clazz.getEnumConstants()).anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(string1));
```

The client now looks like this,

```
boolean test = biPre.test("DOG", Animal.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the class in which the `biPre` is defined as generic similar to the function `validateEnum`.

```
public class Test<E extends Enum<E>> {
    BiPredicate<String,Class<E>> biPre = (string1,clazz) -> EnumSet.allOf(clazz).stream().anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(string1));
}
```

Then you can test it like this:

```
boolean isValid = biPre.test( "DOG", (Class<E>) Animal.class);
```